# Проблема с версией Python и PyCharm. В PyCharm будто свой терминал\окружение

Tags: linux, pycharm

Всем привет. Окружение Linux Mint 20

Думаю на скрине видно проблему. В PyCharm будто своя версия Python

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Туда же можно отнести еще одну проблему

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Мне почему-то кажется, что в PyCharm проблема. В чем может быть дело ?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Как вариант сравнить переменные окружения `echo $PATH` и проверить пути к python3, командой `whereis python3`, возможно это поможет в вашей проблеме

Comment: @PotroNik как может быть что пайчарм и терминал видят разные файлы, при чем если перейти физически в /usr/bin, то там будет как раз python3.8 файлы. А PytCharm почему-то видит 3.7 вместо всего этого

Comment: @ValentynAnzhurov передача параметров переменных сред может быть изменена в программе, посмотрите похожую тему, возможно изменения как раз внесены в конфигурации программы https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42708389/how-to-set-environment-variables-in-pycharm

Comment: Скорее всего системный shell (bash?) дополнительно настраивается какими-то конфигурационными файлами, которые не видит PyCharm. `.bashrc` он прочесть должен, а вот что-то посложнее может и упустить. Для начала стоит разобраться где конкретно docker executable добавляется в PATH.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В общем я не смог разобраться с "$PATH сеанса" и тд. В итоге просто снес тот PyCharm что установил из Software manager и поставил через JetBrains toolbox. Помогло

Answer (score 1):

> В чем может быть дело ?

А в чём проблема? Если в том, что Вы видите **разные** версии интерпретатора Python, то задать конкретную версию Python можно отдельно для каждого проекта в меню:

```
File / Settings / Project / Project interpreter
```

Comment: Все бы ничего, но там нет Python 3.8, который физически присутствует у меня на компе

Comment: @ValentynAnzhurov "но там нет Python 3.8" - значит PyCharm не види его. По какой причине - сложно сказать. Может быть его нет в переменной $PATH  того сеанса, в котором вы запускаете PyCharm.